# Transfer a file with sockets and find maximum mtu

Tags: python, sockets

i'm trying to transfer a file from the sender to the receiver such that the packets are not fragmented en-route. This is composed of two tasks: (1) find out the maximal fragmentation unit (MTU) of the minimal MTU on the path from the sender to the receiver, and (2) then transfer a file in packets that do not exceed the minimal MTU between a receiving and sending host.

**the code that I have to the receiver is:**

```
# ----    Imports     ---- # 
from socket import *
import sys, struct, time


# ----   Constants    ---- #
HOST            = ""
PORT            = 5555
ADDRESS         = (HOST,PORT)
PORT_MSGS               = 9999
TIMEOUT         = 0.0005
BUFFER                  = 65536


#---        Body        --- #
mtu = 0
numMsgs = 0

#make a socket
try:
    sckt = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_DGRAM)
    sckt.bind(ADDRESS)
    sckt.settimeout(TIMEOUT)
except socket.error:
    if sckt:
        sckt.close() # Socket Creation Failed
        sys.exit(1) # Exit program with error


#get mtu and number of messages
header = struct.pack('c','k')
while (1):  
    try:
        data, addr = sckt.recvfrom(BUFFER)
        char = struct.unpack('lc', data[0:5])[1]
        if (char == 'm'):
            mtu = struct.unpack('lc', data[0:5])[0]
            numMsgs = int(data[5:])
            #send ack for the mtu message
            sckt.sendto(header, (addr[0] ,PORT_MSGS))
            break
        if not(char == 'm'):
            continue
    except socket.error:
        continue
    except timeout:
        continue


mtuFileName = sys.argv[1]
fileName= sys.argv[2]

#make mtu file
mtuFile = open(mtuFileName,'wb')
mtuFile.write(str(mtu))
mtuFile.close()

f = open(fileName,'wb')

packetsBuffer = numMsgs * [0]
# Receive messages
packetCounter = 0
data, addr = sckt.recvfrom(BUFFER)
while (1):
        packetSeq = int(struct.unpack('lc', data[0:5])[0])
        char = struct.unpack('lc', data[0:5])[1]
        if (char == 'r') and (packetsBuffer[packetSeq] == 0):
            dataOfPack = data[5:]
            packetsBuffer[packetSeq] = dataOfPack
            packetCounter = packetCounter + 1
        if( numMsgs == packetCounter):
            break
        data, addr = sckt.recvfrom(BUFFER)


#write messages to file
buffIndex = 0
while (buffIndex < numMsgs):
    f.write(packetsBuffer[buffIndex])
    buffIndex = buffIndex + 1


f.close()
sckt.close() # close the socket
```

**the sender is:**

```
# -------    Imports    ------- #
from socket import *
import sys, struct, os, stat, commands, time


# -------   Constants    ------- #
PORT_SEND           = 5555
IP_HOST         = sys.argv[1]
SERVER_ADDRESS      = (IP_HOST  ,PORT_SEND)
MY_PORT             = 9999
MAX_FAILS_SENDING   = 10
MTU_DISCOVERY_SEQ   = 0 # the Sequence number sending MTU discovery messages
TIMEOUT             = 0.0005
BUFFER              = 65536


# -------     Body       ------- #
#socket- file
try:
    scktFile = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_DGRAM)
    scktFile.connect(SERVER_ADDRESS)
    scktFile.settimeout(TIMEOUT)
except socket.error:
    if scktFile:
        scktFile.close() # Socket Creation Failed
        sys.exit(1) # Exit program with error


#socket- ack/mtu
try:
    scktMsgs = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_DGRAM)
    scktMsgs.bind(("", MY_PORT))
    scktMsgs.settimeout(TIMEOUT)
except socket.error:
    if scktMsgs:
        scktMsgs.close() # Socket Creation Failed
        sys.exit(1) # Exit program with error


#find the mtu
mtu = int(commands.getoutput(" tracepath "+sys.argv[1]+"| grep -i resume | awk '{print $3}'"))

payloadSize = mtu-(20+8+8+5)

fileName = sys.argv[2]
f = open (fileName, 'rb') 

fileData = f.read(99999999)
fileLen = len(fileData)
numMsgs = fileLen / (payloadSize)
if((fileLen % payloadSize) != 0):
    numMsgs = numMsgs + 1


#m - mtu,k - mtu ack, a - ack, f - fin, r - regular message part of file, w - wait for ack - after  10 rounds, n -name of file
while (1):  
    header = struct.pack('lc', mtu, 'm') #m - mtu
    sNumMsgs = str(numMsgs)
    scktFile.sendto(header+sNumMsgs, SERVER_ADDRESS)
    try:
        data,addr = scktFile.recvfrom(BUFFER)
        char = struct.unpack('c', data[0])
        if char == 'k':
            break
    except socket.error:
        continue
    except timeout:
        continue


# send file content
seqNum = 0
header = struct.pack('lc', seqNum, 'r')#r - regular message part of file
while (1):
        seqNum = 0
        indexFile = 0
        header = struct.pack('lc', seqNum, 'r')
        data = fileData[indexFile:(indexFile+payloadSize)]
        indexFile = indexFile + payloadSize
        while (data):
            if(scktFile.sendto(header+data,SERVER_ADDRESS)):
                data = fileData[indexFile:(indexFile+payloadSize)]
                indexFile = indexFile+payloadSize
            #time.sleep(0.00005)
            seqNum = seqNum + 1
            seqNum = seqNum % numMsgs # Maximum Seq number
            header = struct.pack('lc', seqNum, 'r')
            if seqNum == 0:
                break


scktMsgs.close()
scktFile.close()
```

I keep getting the error "0 points (No Output)" and I dont know why

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this.

1. It is already the responsibility of the TCP stack to ensure that outgoing packets conform to the path MTU. Why you would want to assume that responsibility in the application as well is a mystery to me.
2. There is no API that I am aware of that tells you the MTU ahead of any data transfer.
3. There is no way to control the outgoing packet size. TCP is a byte stream protocol, not a packet exchange, and it is entitled to coalesce outgoing packets whenever it feels like it. Turning off the Nagle algorithm can mitigate that but it isn't guaranteed to eliminate it.
4. There is no benefit. It is well established that the most efficient way to transfer bulk data over TCP is to write in as large chunks as possible; set a large socket send buffer at the sender; and set a large socket receive buffer at the receiver.